# yii2 urlManager enablePrettyUrl not work with IndexController

Tags: yii2, yii-url-manager

My config:

```
'urlManager' => [
    'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
    'showScriptName' => false,
    'rules' => [
        '<alias:login|logout>' => 'site/<alias>',
    ],
]
```

My .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php
```

my controllers: [my controllers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h5brv.png)

I tested example.com/home/test, example.com/login and example.com/index.php/index/test work, but example.com/index/test 404, I have to use example.com/index.php/index/test .

any suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: So `example.com/index.php/index/test` is what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: no,  make example.com/index/test work.

Comment: Should work. If `index.php?r=index/test` works without the urlManager config, `/index/test` should work now. I'm not very familiar with .htaccess files but are you sure the settings are loaded correctly?

Comment: the .htaccess files is ok. if i modify the name of IndexController(eg. TestController), /test/test will work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On your `htaccess` file the first rewrite condition reads:

"if the file is not directly found then..."

This condition will fail and the rewrite rule won't get applied when requesting actions on `IndexController`

The second reads: "if the directory is not directly found then..."

The first condition fails because you named one of your controllers `IndexController`, it **conflicts with the name of `index.php`**.

When you request an action on the `HomeController` the server first tries to find a `home.html` or `home.php` file, since it can't find it, it uses the rewrite rule and you get the expected result, the action on your controller runs.

But, when you try to run `index/test` the server first tries to find `index.html` or `index.php`, the file is found so the rewrite rule doesn't get applied. Then the server tries to serve the `index/test` file but it can't find it and returns 404.

You could rearrange your controllers, right now you have three *home* controllers, `SiteController`, `HomeController` and `IndexController`, do you really need the three of them?

Otherwise might be able to change your rewrite rules somehow to make it work, but I'm not sure exactly how to do it, I would think that it would be something along the lines of making the first rewrite condition more strict to make sure that only matching the exact file path stops the rewriting.

If you do modify `.htaccess` make sure afterwards that your static resources are still being served correctly.

Comment: thanks for your answer, i just want to figure out the reason, not really need three home controllers. thank you.